# After unselecting an icon the select-rectangle does not dissapear

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, gui

[image]

Here's what I'm talking about. After I selected this icon (or any icon for that mater) and clicked on the blue background (the desktop) thus un-selecting the icon the dotted select rectangle still remains.

I know it's a joke to most of you, but this is driving my OCD in overdrive. I need it resolved.

I use Win7 64Bit if that matters.

Comment: It would appear you have Aero turned off, correct?

Comment: No, it's turned on alright.